# alinhamento responsivo no footer

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de uma ajuda para alinhar o `footer` na responsividade. Colocar o copyright descendo mais abaixo (já tentei `padding`, mas ele some) e alinhar os separadores na `section(border-right)`, o resto tá funcionando, deixarei aqui o [codepen](http://codepen.io/x-gyba/pen/pEmyRk).

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-wrap;
}

footer{
  Position:relative;  
  align-self:flex-end;
  background-color:#222;
  color:#fff;
  min-height:2;
  text-align: center;
  width:100%;
}

footer:after{
  content: '\00a9  Infogyba Soluções em Ti  ';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #8c8c96;
  font-size:1em;
  font-weight:600;
  font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  bottom:0;  
  display:block;
}

.section{
  float:left;
  width:33%;  
  height:auto;
  border-right:1px;  
  border-right-style: outset;  
} 

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  .section{
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
   }
}

footer td,h2{
  font-size:1em;
  font-weight:600;
  font-family: 'Arial',sans-serif;
  text-align:center;
  display:inline-block;
}

footer .section  a:hover{
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: rotacao; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera (nome da animação)*/
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera (Duração da animação)*/
  animation-name: rotacao; /* nome da animação */
  animation-duration: 2s; /* Duração da animação */
}

@keyframes rotacao {
  from {transform: rotate(1deg);}
  to {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@media screen and(max-width:768){
  footer{
    padding-bottom: 3em;
  }
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class ="section">
    <h2>Nosso endereço:</h2>
    <br>
    <td>Rua blalal, 132 - Irajá</td>
    <td>Rio de Janeiro Cidade - RJ.</td>
    <td>Cep: 21300-630</td>
    <br>  
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td>blablabla@gmail.com</td>  
  </div>
  <div class ="section">
    <h2>Consulte-nos:</h2>
    <br>    
    <td>Telefone: (21)9999-9999</td>
    <td>Horário de Atendimento</td>
    <td>de Seg a Sexta: 08:00 as 17:00</td>  
  </div> 
  <div class ="section">
    <h2>Fale conosco nas Redes Sociais:</h2><br> 
    <td><a href="#"><img src="imagens/facebook.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="imagens/twitter.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="imagens/youtube.png"></a>
      <a href="#"><img src="imagens/google.png"></a>
    </br></td>   
</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: ja tentou colocar `.section {width: 33%;}` ?

Comment: sim , desloca para baixo.

Comment: Você quer que as sections continuem centralizadas é isso?

Comment: sim e colocar o copyright para descer abaixo do conteudo qdo eu reduzir a pagina,só isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar algumas outras propriedades do css com o `flex`, veja abaixo;

```
footer {
    display: flex;
}
.section {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

A propriedade `flex: 1` define que cada elemento dentro de `footer` (sections) deve preencher o espaço de forma com que todo o `width` seja preenchido.

Comment: ficou bom , mas o copyright não aparece.

Comment: @ClaytonCampos coloque o copyright em uma div especifica, sera melhor desta maneira, e fazendo isso você tambem pode colocar um link no nome para facilitar as pessoas a te acharem e etc.

Comment: vlw , vou acertar o copyright ,obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Amigo, ta um pouco confuso a estruturação, não entendi porque colocou o texto no rodapé em um `footer:after`

Mas o que esta causando essa dor de cabeça é que você deixou com posição absoluta e o `bottom: 0px`

Então tirei a posição absoluta para relativa e funcionou tranquilamente, tente isso:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {  
  footer:after{
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

Comment: falta de café, rs...obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tira o conteúdo de texto de dentro do CSS, isso vai contra todas as boas práticas possíveis.
Coloca ele em uma div própria com conteúdo devido, se for pra ser oculto ou qualquer outra coisa assim, usa os @media como o amigo Lennon indicou!